# 'Recordset' works differently depending on 'new' or 'CreateObject'

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ado

It dose not work [rs.RecordCount] on recordset made by [new ADODB.Recordset].
But it can work [rs.RecordCount] on recordset made by [CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")].

By the way, it also dosen't work [rs.fields([integer])] on recordset made by [CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")].
But it can work on [rs.fields([integer])] on recordset made by [new ADODB.Recordset]

How can I use two source([rs.fields([integer])] and [rs.RecordCount]) on one recordset?

```vb
Sub all_column()
    Call connectDB

    Dim strSql As String
    Dim Syntax As String
    Dim recordsAffected As Long
    Dim nameOfTable As String
    Dim numberOfRecord As Integer
    Dim i, next_i As Integer


    Set rsTable = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rsTable.CursorLocation = adUseClient

    'This is query'
    strSql = "show tables"

    'Set recordset by [CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")]'
    'just for return of [.RecordCount]'
    'Because of [.RecordCount] dose not work on [new ADODB.Recordset]'
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
    rs.Open strSql, cn, adOpenStatic
    numberOfRecord = rs.RecordCount
    rs.Close

    'Set recordset by [New ADODB.Recordset]'
    'because of [.Fields(0)] dose not work on [CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")]'
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open strSql, cn, adOpenStatic
    i = 2

    Do While rs.EOF = False
        nameOfTable = rs.Fields(0).Value
        strSql = "DESC " + nameOfTable + ";"
        rsTable.Open strSql, cn, adLockReadOnly

        next_i = i + rsTable.RecordCount

        Sheets("sheet1").Range("b" + CStr(i)).CopyFromRecordset rsTable
        Sheets("sheet1").Range("a" + CStr(i) + ":a" + CStr(next_i - 1)).Value = nameOfTable

        i = next_i

        rsTable.Close
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop

    rs.Close
    cn.Close
End Sub
```

> ADO = Microsoft Active X Data Objects 6.1 Library
>
> SQL = 5.7.14-google-log (Google)
>
> EXCEL = Microsoft Excel 2016 MSO (16.0.10228.20080)

Comment: In any late-bound CreateObject there are limited properties and methods available. I can cite you several exemptions from a Scripting.Dictionary object that was created late-bound vs. a New early-bound version with a MS Scripting Run-Time project reference.

Comment: The limitations can usually be worked around but if you want full functionality use early-bound with a reference.

Comment: @Jeeped So if I use early-bound, then I can use both source?

Comment: @Jeeped Is there example of early-bound reference?

Comment: If I remember correctly, rs.RecordCount's validity is relative to the type of recordset you are retrieving; e.g. dynaset, static, etc. With some you need to goto last then goto first to get an accurate count. google rs.RecordCount for specifics.

Comment: @Jeeped I concur - I've struggled with that many times in the past.

Comment: @CindyMeister ... and one of the best reasons for giving up on the whole mess was MS pushing ADO while MS-Access was and is still built on DAO.

Comment: @Jeeped I can sort of understand the logic - ADO knowledge can be more universally applied... I still use and very much appreciate Access - it's a very useful tool for individuals or small groups. But very difficult to upscale!